# I need to create an auto-generated email when items in a Sharepoint list are created or updated

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, email, alert

I'm pretty inexperienced with Sharepoint design, but have taken on the task of creating a basic issue tracker for a project. The idea is when testers find an issue, they will log it into the Sharepoint, where there is the input field "AssignedTo".

I need an email to be sent to the people entered into this field and then an email sent to the same group whenever one of the Assigned people updates the item in my list.

I know this requires a workflow most likely to achieve, but I'm having difficulty finding an appropriate source of assistance that isn't above my level of understanding.

Hopefully I can find some help here. Thanks.

**Edit:** I'm using Sharepoint Designer 2010

Comment: Please include a tag or mention of the version (2007, 2010, 2013) of SharePoint.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Workflow it is. A very simple one should suffice.

In the explanation below I'm using SharePoint 2013 and Office 365, but it's absolutely the same in SP2010 or/and on premises, and even in SP2007 the process is very similar.

You will need SharePoint Designer installed on your computer.

Creating workflow:

1. Open SharePoint designer
2. Open your site
3. Go to Workflows
4. Click 'List Workflow' on ribbon and select your list

   [image]
5. Add 'Send email' action

   [image]
6. The following block will be added to your workflow:

   [image]
7. Configure 'Send email' action to use assigned to field for determining recipient emails

   [image]

   Also define the body block for the letter. You can use different lookups there, for example inserting values from the item or item URL or whatever.
8. Now go to 'Workflow Settings'

   [image]
9. Setup workflow to start whenever item is added or created

   [image]
10. Publish

    [image]
11. Enjoy :)

    [image]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for these instructions. That worked perfectly. I was about to delete the list and try again.

Now, off to figure out how to format the email correctly!

Comment: These were great instructions - very clear. Unfortunately, I can't get mine to send an email. I have no idea why it's not working... Is there something I could check?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I tried this so much and couldn't figured it out but your walkthrough was perfect!

Comment: Please post your problem as a separate question with more details like your outgoing email being configured properly, other notifications arriving as expected, etc.

Comment: What about "Transition to stage"? It doesn't allow to Publish without filling this section

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's an out of the box [list template for tracking issues](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DfQ0TVZldvWI&ei=GUlZVN-0Jc3paJGRgWA&usg=AFQjCNGzkMBTvANnQNDTNsOw4QYitJit7w&sig2=2nrFqKczr8msFsva-FNY8g&bvm=bv.78677474,d.d2s), called **Issues** as you would expect, it provides most of the basic functionality you mentioned without any SharePoint Designer manipulations involved.

What would be lacking in comparison with workflow solution is the ability to control the message format and contents and additional logic that you can incorporate in SharePoint Designer workflow rules.

And there's an **Issue Tracking Database** site template available in Enterprise versions of SharePoint Server, that's based on Access Services. You might want to [explore its capabilities](https://support.office.com/article/Video-Use-the-Issues-Web-Database-template-D75EA857-DA68-40EE-993A-BA5EE813A95C) as well to see what else could be improved in your solution.