# Generating an email alert for new post in site feed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, email, newsfeed

I am working with sharepoint online 2013 and Sharepoint designer 2013.

I wanted to generate an email alert for the Site Feed App.
I wanted to send an email to a group of people with the posted content and the name of the person who posted the content.
I tried the method explained in the following question.

"[I need to create an auto-generated email when items in a Sharepoint list are created or updated](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre)"

It worked for the other lists(Document Libraries etc)
But the workflow i created for Site Feed only generates and email when a user replies to a post.
I tried almost all the combinations in the Start Options of Workflow Settings.

http://goo.gl/9HznDG

How can change the settings of the workflow so that it generate an email for a new post in site feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my colleagues found out a solution for this.

First we have to create a Site workflow for this.Not a list workflow for site feed.

In the site workflow we have to create a loop.

[image: Site Workflow]

In the workflow first we have to create an infinite loop and wait for a item adding event for Microfeed list.

[image]

Then in the email action we can add lookups for the attributes in the item.

[image]

In the add look up window we can use following settings to get the values in the item.

[image]

Save and publish the workflow.
Now it will send an email to the users mentioned in the workflow once a new post is added to the site feed/news feed/micro feed.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft have now disabled Microfeed from view in site contents and in action 'Wait for Event in List Item.

[image]

**Workaround**

Open SharePoint Designer

Click All Files > Lists > Right click Published Feed > Properties > Under Settings untick Hide from browser and save.
[image]

Then go back to your workflow and select 'Wait for Event in List Item' under action and the Microfeed should now be visable under List again.
[image]