# Collect data from a form

Tags: email, custom-form

I a new to Sharepoint and I have a page on Sharepoint 2013 that has a form on it. I want it on submit to send the data filled to the server and store it somewhere or if possible send an email to a recipient.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: You could always create an email workflow that send the values from the form when a new item is created or modified.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-HA010239042.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What is the "form" that you have mentioned, is it a web part ? You can store the data filled on the form into a SharePoint custom list. Create a custom list with all the fields that you want to store data for. If you are looking to use the server side code refer to [this](http://www.sharepointblog.in/2013/04/add-new-list-item-to-sharepoint-list.html) link which expalins how to add data to a SharePoint list through code. To trigger an email, you can write a [sharepoint designer workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre) or write an event receiver on **ItemAdded** so that you can programatically trigger an email when list item is added to the list.