# Implementing workflows to all sharepoint sites in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, workflow

[I need to create an auto-generated email when items in a Sharepoint list are created or updated](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre)

Based on above link I have generated an automatic email to items created. Now I want to implement the same for all project sites old and new both and to all the lists in project sites
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy task, you have to manually do this, unless someone tells any code for this...

If you have two **similar lists** in two different site-collections in SharePoint and want to copy an existing workflow from site A to site B you can follow the procedure below.

So, to achieve the same follow the steps below.

1. In the first(source) site, create the required workflow and publish
   it.
2. Now select **Export to Visio** option which allows you to save the
   workflow with a .vwi extension. (Refer this workflow hereafter as
   source workflow).
3. Now go to the destination site where you want the workflow to be
   copied, and create a new workflow with the same name as the previous
   one & publish it.
4. Now select **Export to Visio** option which allows you to save the
   workflow with a .vwi extension. (Refer this workflow hereafter as
   Destination workflow).
5. Now you will be having two .vwi files (one of source workflow’s –
   **SourceWorkflowName.vwi**  and other of the destination workflow’s –
   **DestinationWorkflowName.vwi**). Now add .zip extension to both the
   files. Now your files names should be **SourceWorkflowName.vwi.zip** &
   **DestinationWorkflowName.vwi.zip**.
6. Now open both the zip files, copy **workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml** from
   destination workflow to source workflow. (**Its destination to source
   and not source to destination**).
7. From now on, we will not use the file
   **DestinationWorkflowName.vwi.zip**.  So ignore that file.
8. Remove the .zip extension from **SourceWorkflowName.vwi.zip** which
   gives you the   **SourceWorkflowName.vwi** file.
9. Now, go to the destination site, open workflows and click **Import
   from Visio** and browse to the **SourceWorkflowName.vwi** file.
10. That’s it and your workflow is copied. You can publish the workflow
     and run it.

**Note:** In case if your list’s GUID’s (for those lists that you have used in workflow – tasks list, history list or any other lists used in workflow steps) have been changed from source & destination site, you may need to update those steps in the workflow.

http://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/copyingmoving-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflows/

http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/how-to-copy-workflows-from-one-site-collection-to-another-with

**Or Use this Codeplex solution** [Sharepoint Workflow Migrator](http://spwflmigrator.codeplex.com/)

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointwarrior/archive/2012/03/14/sp-2010-how-to-copy-workflows-from-one-site-collection-to-another.aspx

Comment: what about same workflow for all the lists in same site?