# Workflow with conditions

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, designer

I just joined StackExchange and am unable to post a comment to this thread:  [I need to create an auto-generated email when items in a Sharepoint list are created or updated](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre)

We have a solution in place that is almost identical to Andrey's solution however, we need 2 separate emails.  In our instance a group of people gets an email when an item in a list is moved into a **scheduled** status.

Unfortunately when the item is created or changed we get the same notification. What we want is when the item is changed we get a separate email that somehow alerts us to the fact that the item has indeed changed (instead of the same email that looks like it was created).

I hope this makes sense. Basically we just want to add a step for a different notification if the item is changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a workflow, you can choose when the WF should start. So what you need to do is to adjust the current workflow to only kick in when the item is created and create another WF to run when the item is modified (with a different email body).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two different Workflows on the List to achieve what you are looking for. In the Workflow Settings, Set Start workflow automatically when an item is created for one and item is changed for another.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use SharePoint alerts? You can have folks that need to be aware of these changes added to an AD or SharePoint group and then alert on this group. I know you can alert on the AD group but not too sure about the SP group.

Add this `_layouts/SubChoos.aspx` to the end of the site url. Do not include the page folder or page name.

ex. `http://somesite.me/testsite/pages/test.aspx` replace pages/test.aspx with above so it reads `http://somesite.me/testsite/_layouts/SubChoos.aspx` this will take you into the alert options. Select the resources you want to be alerted on and answer the on screen and prompted info.

You can also set alerts on views. This is very helpful because you can filter a view and when an Item is added because it meets the requirements then it can fire off an alert to a group of users.