# Sending an E-mail to a Creator of an Event

Tags: email

I have a calendar set up where when a user creates a new event, an alert it sent to me so that I may Approve or Deny it. The problem is, I also would like to have an e-mail sent to the event creator that says if I approved or denied it. I've tried messing around with alerts more, but I feel like that's a dead end.

It probably can be done with workflows, but I don't quite understand how they work. Could someone explain?

Comment: Which SharePoint version you are using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2016

Comment: Is it working for you? Did my answer helps you in getting it?

Comment: Have you tried the VS solution or you simply go with my given solution?

Comment: Please let us know about the solution if you get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating workflow:

1. Open SharePoint designer 2013
2. Open your site
3. Go to Workflows
4. Click 'List Workflow' on ribbon and select your list
5. Add 'Send email' action
6. The following block will be added to your workflow:
7. Configure 'Send email' action to use assigned to field for determining recipient emails. Also define the body block for the letter. You can use different lookups there, for example inserting values from the item or item URL or whatever.
8. Now go to 'Workflow Settings'
9. Setup workflow to start whenever item is added or created
10. Publish
11. Enjoy :)

Find the detailed explanation in below link.

[create an auto-generated email when items in a Sharepoint list are created](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre)

**Note:-**

- Workflow steps are same for SharePoint 2016 as mentioned above.
- Choose the calendar list in step 4.

Comment: So this will send an e-mail as soon as I accept/deny the event? Or does it only send an e-mail when an event is added?

Comment: It sends an email when new event is added to calendar.

Comment: You had mentioned here that "I have a calendar set up where when a user creates a new event, an alert it sent to me". & It will work like the same.

Comment: I already have an alert system in place for when new events are created. I'm looking for a way to send an e-mail when I accept or deny a newly created event. Is that possible with workflows?

Comment: Yes you can create a condition on update an item that if status is accept or denied than you can send an email.

Comment: Run the workflow on create (not update). You need to a `wait for field to change` action before the `send email` step, to wait until the status changes.

Comment: What if I'm not using SharePoint designer?

Comment: You need to use Visual Studio to create workflow. Here is the example of VS approval workflow....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456545.aspx

Comment: Did you get it working for you?

Comment: @Luke, Did you get it working? If you need further help than please let me know here..

Answer (score 0):

You can use alerts, but the email will not be customizable.  It will only be a notice that the status changed from "pending" to "approved" or "denied".  Just add a column with the above 3 choices and with pending being the default.  Create a view of the calendar with status not equal pending.  Set alerts on this view for each of your contributors.

But I would also recommend looking at the OOTB approval workflow.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-60c865df-3f10-4aa2-8331-60b736a5e3d5

Comment: What if I don't have a set list of contributors? I want to send the alert to the person who created the event that got accepted/denied, whoever that may be.

Comment: Then the Approval Workflow is what you want.  Or a custom workflow as Hardik suggested.