# Annoucements Keyword Alert Custom Email Groups

Tags: alert, announcements

How do I setup an email alert for specific people on certain topics/keywords in an announcement? Right now anyone I assign will get an email alert for every announcement (which I don't want)

Example:

```
Announcement - Topic 1; emails person A
Announcement - Topic 2; emails person B
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a designer work flow or write a event receiver for new item added event on this list to send out emails. I don't think there is OOO option for this.

Comment: Is there a step by step guide somewhere? I tried the workflow and it didn't work so I'm sure I created it incorrectly.

Comment: You can check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre  to get started and then add a condition before sending the mail.