# Looking to do a workflow, not sure where to start

Tags: workflow

Essentially, I would like a hiring manager to go to Sharepoint and fill out a document. Once that is completed, the IT admin would need to be notified. Once the IT admin had done his duties, he would then click or submit something alerting the hiring manager of its completion. If possible, i would like to have each event timestamped. I am new to Sharepoint so go easy =)

Comment: Are you using SharePoint out of the box, SharePoint Designer, or some other tool?  Which version of SharePoint and/or your other tools are you using?

Comment: I am using Sharepoint Online but also downloaded Sharepoint Designer..

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible. I have only worked with this in SharePoint 2010/2013 but it seem pretty simple. [Example of an email workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre)
I should be fairly simple to create the results you want. I would some if logic and a check to make sure each part is done. The initial email would send once created, I.T would do their duties, check it is finished, submit it and then it would email again.