# Programmatically poll commit log

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, email, check-in

You'll have to excuse my ignorance and lack of knowledge of SharePoint, since the back-end side of things is new to me. I am however an experienced C# .NET developer so not totally clueless.

What I want to know is if it is possible to access the commit messages for documents in my SharePoint libraries? I would like to be able regularly iterate through new versions, check the commit messages for specific syntax using RegEx, and then forward an email to a specific address if the syntax is found. Has anyone done this before? I've tried some searches but maybe I just don't know the terminology, because I haven't found anything.

Is this actually something that I can control with a workflow? i.e. when a document is checked in, can I parse the check in message and send an email if it contains a specific pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed this by creating a SharePoint 2010 List Workflow that would check if the Check In Comment contained text that matched a RegEx then emailed an appropriate address. Followed instructions at [I need to create an auto-generated email when items in a Sharepoint list are created or updated](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre)