# Send email to a user when Items created or updated in List

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

[image]I have tried with the way below, but it auto-sent a lot of email per second. **See the photo attached**
Please help me with that. I just need to send an email to user who chose in the textbox. So this user will follow up the task. Thank you so much !!
Link:
[I need to create an auto-generated email when items in a Sharepoint list are created or updated](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre/120028#120028?newreg=40dfa6782e8b45cda368331ee10a7f77)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you add Approval step in Designer Workflow, it will add email step automatically. you need to delete those default steps by going inside the approval step

Just click on the approval step and it will open you a page where you will get option "Change behavior of single task". click on that and you will see the email steps added there. just remove those steps from there and publish your workflow again. this should resolve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your information, I have added a problem photo in my question to share more details.

Comment: could you paste the screen shot of your workflow here?

Comment: Yes, another photo added in my question pls. Thanks for your help