# Customizes Alert depending on person named in column (without designer)

Tags: alert

I want to create an alert. The person who gets the alert shall be dependent on whats filled in the column "assigned to". Is this possible? or can you only put a specific person or group in the question box " alert send to" ?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please give more info. Such as sharepoint version, tools you have access to, etc.

Comment: I have SP Workspace, but I can't find any use for it. That's it really... And I don't know the version of the SP :/

Comment: I don’t get email alerts when I create alerts for specific list view filter.. Alerts for other generic list/docs/workflow are all working… Can you guide me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this a couple of different ways. You can create a  [Sharepoint Designer Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre/)  which sends an email based on that field value.

Or you could create an MS Flow online that would run when a new item is created. The process would be:

1. Create column with Type of person
   [image]

Finished List!

[image: Finished List]

3. Create a Ms Flow
4. Select the trigger "When an item is created"

[image]

5.Select your site and list name

6.Add new outlook action "Send an email"

7.Set "To" to "Assigned to Email"

[image]

From there you set the subject and body to whatever you like.

Comment: Thak you so much! But unfortunately the designer is not working for me, so that's why im stuck :((

Comment: This is not sharepoint designer. This is another 365 app called Flow

Comment: But it's not for free, right? I need a longtherm solution, without creating account or sth...

Comment: Do you see an option above your list/library that says "flow"? it should come with your 365 subscription.

Comment: No, it isnt't there... Maybe my version is too old.

Comment: Ya flow is only for Sharepoint Online

Comment: Miriam - you need to determine which version of Sharepoint you are using.  Then google Sharepoint Designer Download - you can download this for free from the Microsoft website

Answer (score 1):

Alerts are inflexible and the options are limited.  I'm using Sharepoint 2013, you've not said which version you are using, but in 2010 + 2013 the menu is the same.

If using Alerts instead of Sharepoint Designer is really your only option, then you could test the following to see if it will meet your needs.

Make a view on your list with a filter, select your 'people or group field' - your field is called 'assigned to', my example has a field called 'action owner'.  Set the value to [Me].

[image]

Create a new alert - see the picture below, set the alert to be triggered 'when someone changes an item that appears in the following view'.  So if someone changes one of your items, Sharepoint should send an email alert.

However, you'll need to test whether or not this works as intended.  I have had mixed success with alerts.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Yeah unfortunately this is not working for me, because I don't want an alert send to myself, but to the person, who is named in that particular column...

Comment: If you are the Sharepoint Administrator you have the power to set up alerts for other people.  Then [Me] = whoever you set up the alert for.  If you are not Sharepoint Admin, each user will need to configure this alert.

Comment: OK, I see.. but it's not working. In my process, THE person is not defined at the beginnig, but in the middel. And I only want this notification once. So if the Item is changed afterwargs again, I don't want to get another alert.

Comment: Look at the screen shot in my answer -> there is Change Type.  Change Type gives you (limited) ways to define when you want the alert to be sent.  The person does not need to be defined in the beginning, but the alert will only be sent once you have a) defined a person and b) when the Change Type criteria are satisfied.  Given that alerts are so limited in how they can be configured, I doubt you are going to find a satisfactory way to configure it.  Back to point b) - send alert when either a new item is made or modified - neither of these options meet your requirements.  SP Designer is needed

Comment: Oh well... I giuess you're right :/ So I will need to come up with a completely new solutions, as SP Designer is blocked for me :( but thank you anyway! The problem with b) is, that I would get 2 alerts, if i do 2 modifications...

Comment: Yes b) will keep sending alerts indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done by creating a SharePoint designer workflow , with an action of sending E-mail to the person based on Item field , in your case "assigned to" field.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Unfortunately I am not allowed to use it :(