# List alerts does not work in a site created through site template

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, alert

I have saved a site as a site template. In the site I have a list for which the alert is set to send email every time a new item is added to list. But when I created a new site using this site template then I don't have the alert there.

Does the alerts don't get saved when we save a site as site template?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the simple answer is no. Email alerts and personal views are user generated parts of SharePoint that can not be saved to a site or list template.

Think of it as an email feed that users can control. Email alerts are organized on each site you visit, therefore if the site is new users must sign up for the email alerts they want as it is an open optional choice.

Answer (score 0):

Email alerts will not save to site template , but you can create a workflow with send email action in SPD instead of "Alert" function . Site templates support workflows .

1. Open SharePoint designer and open your site , create an [email workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre) when new item added .
2. Save the site as template .
3. Export the template .
4. Upload the template .
5. Create a new site using this template .

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/save-download-and-upload-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template