# How to send an email to a user based on item's change

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I would like to have an email sent out when an item is MODIFIED ONLY. I would prefer this be done through a workflow and no other additional apps/programs. I know there is a "Send an email when an item is created or modified" workflow event but this is for both created or modified, I need it for a modified item only. Any ideas?

Comment: Please Refer to the below possible solution for you [Click Here for solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre)

Comment: @AIM4DREAM thanks, but it seems that this solution can only be achieved through the use of SharePoint designer which I don't have SharePoint Designer and have no ability of getting it installed on my machine at the moment. I am looking to find a solution within the SharePoint online workflows system

Comment: When you create a SharePoint workflow you can set the workflow to run on item changes only using the **Start workflow automatically when an item is changed** checkbox. Does that not work for you?

Comment: I am assuming you are using Flow to trigger the mail, in that case this may help: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/3821506240744debadcd89c94690652d/when-an-item-in-a-sharepoint-list-is-modified-send-an-email/

Answer (score 1):

You can create SharePoint Designer workflow, in the workflow settings just choose checkbox "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed", don't choose "Start workflow automatically when an item is created".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an alert on the list / library would be more straight forward, you can trigger alerts to fire on item update.

Comment: this would be great if I wanted the alerts to be sent to the same person every time. Unfortunately, I want the email to be sent only to the people selected in the respective item(s) so this would have to be through a workflow as I said

Comment: @aNobleNoob is it one user or multiple users? associated with the item?? and what type of column did you used for that?

Comment: @AIM4DREAM it is multiple users, multiple columns. I know how to set up the email part, I just need to have the trigger only go off when an item is modified...

Answer (score 0):

If its one user here is the solution

[image]

Here you see two options you can use them or you can choose people picker if its one user and configure the flow accordingly

[image]

Comment: this sends an email when an item is CREATED or MODIFIED, I need it to be triggered only by modifying the item and not creating...