# Sending an email from Action in InfoPath 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath-rules, email-action

I have 3 lists:

- LUT_categories (News, Articles, Discussions ...)
- Subscribers    (category, email address)
- Notifications (category, hyperlink to the    item)

When adding/changing items in Notification I want to email the subscribers, based on category. I tried Action Rule in InfoPath but can't find a way. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no send email function in OOTB InfoPath form.

I recommend you use SharePoint Designer to create custom workflow, use "Send Email"
action to relevant email address in Subscribers, and set the workflow automatically start when item is created or changed.

Reference: [I need to create an auto-generated email when items in a SharePoint list are created or updated](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre)