# Mailto: email address prompts all users to "Add account" in SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, outlook, sharepoint-email

I have a service request email field for each line item in SharePoint 2013 to go to a separate person responsible to each specific service. Users have to be able to select this service request field and it is supposed to open up an Outlook email message with defined fields and they just have to send it.  works great until profiles on users systems change and no email is defaulted for Internet explorer.  Then users are prompted to "Add account".  Is their code I can add to the mailto: line that will always select the users outlook so it wont prompt the users??  we have 2000 users and everyone is getting prompted to setup a default account.  security won't let us touch systems profiles.   I have to get this work.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid not.

The **Mailto:** link is used to call the Outlook client on the local machine and then create a new email item. It can only be assigned with the contents we can fill in after we click the **New Email** button in the Outlook client.

The user who clicks the **Mailto:** link will need to configure the Outlook accounts manually on their end to be able to send the email.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  my boss is demanding that 2k people cannot change settings on their computers.  Gov systems.  so we are essentially stuck with this method.   any other way to accomplish this task?

Comment: @JeffSensenbrenner How about using workflow instead? See an example here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre The email would be sent by the workflow instead of users, but you will need to plan how the workflow should be triggered.