# Send email to Created by user after create new event in custom list

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, 2016

I created a custom list and added event content type. Here I want when new item or event created, send email to  created by user.

New item created
Emial: New Item Created email

also how to Send email when the same user did the update to list item

Updated the same list item:
Email to go Item updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using SharePoint 2016, you can create a SharePoint 2013 designer workflow to send an email.

Set trigger (Start Options) of designer workflow to **Start workflow automatically when an item is created**.

Check below thread for complete steps to create designer workflow:

[I need to create an auto-generated email when items in a Sharepoint list are created or updated](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre)

Comment: Hi i managed to send email when new item created by creating send email action in SP designer , but here how to send different email when the same item is updated by created by user

Comment: please check i updated my question

Comment: If Email body is same, you can set start options of same workflow to start workflow automatically when an item is modified/updated

Comment: Or you can create a new workflow just with single trigger set to start workflow automatically when an item is modified/updated.

Comment: Hi, did you try my suggestions? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way.

Comment: Hi can i add in same workflow for different email subject and body for new item created and same item updated

Comment: You can add **if-else** conditions in workflow. add condition like: `if Created is equal to Modified` --> send creation email (action), `else` --> send update email (action).